# Event driven select statement

Tags: sql-server

I have an event driven mssql database that has the following columns.

```
id    job_id    request    response   status    date_time  
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1      15     <message>    null     pending   22-09-2017 08:00:00
 2      15     null       <message>  created   22-09-2017 08:00:01
 3      15     null         null     finished  22-09-2017 08:00:02
 4      16     <message>    null     pending   22-09-2017 08:00:05
 5      17     <message>    null     pending   22-09-2017 08:00:06
 6      17     null         null     pending   22-09-2017 08:00:06
```

I need to make a query that pulls up all the pending status but only the last one of the set. So for example I don't want the id 3 because it already has a finished status. I do want 4 and 6 since those are the latest of the set. However for number 5 I do want the message but that wasn't saved in the last event since there was a time out or whatever so the desired output would be:

```
id      job_id    request    response   status    date_time  
-----------------------------------------------------------
 4        16     <message>    null     pending   22-09-2017 08:00:05
 6        17     <message>    null     pending   22-09-2017 08:00:06
```

Now the query I thought up now doesn't really work how I want it yet.

```
SELECT id, MAX(job_id), job_id
FROM testtable
HAVING status='pending'
GROUP BY id DESC;
```

I just can't wrap my head around how to mix the two messages together. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use having clause instead of where

Comment: I changed it to having.

Comment: test data with id 6 have request = null, but result set have row with id = 6 and request = <message>

Comment: SELECT id, MAX(job_id), job_id FROM testtable GROUP BY id DESC HAVING status='pending'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try It to get the registers that the last status is pending

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
  ( 
     id         INT 
     ,job_id    INT 
     ,request   VARCHAR(10) 
     ,response  VARCHAR(10) 
     ,status    VARCHAR(10) 
     ,date_time DATETIME 
  ) 

INSERT @table (id,job_id,request,response,status,date_time ) Values
  (1, 15, '<message>',  null     ,'pending ','2017-09-22 08:00:00')
 ,(2, 15, null       ,'<message>','created ','2017-09-22 08:00:01')
 ,(3, 15, null       ,  null     ,'finished','2017-09-22 08:00:02')
 ,(4, 16, '<message>',  null     ,'pending ','2017-09-22 08:00:05')
 ,(5, 17, '<message>',  null     ,'pending ','2017-09-22 08:00:06')
 ,(6, 17, null       ,  null     ,'pending ','2017-09-22 08:00:06');


WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY job_id 
                    ORDER BY id DESC) RowNumber 
                ,* 
         FROM   @table) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rownumber = 1 
       AND status = 'pending'
```

Result

```
RowNumber            id          job_id      request    response   status     date_time
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------
1                    4           16          <message>  NULL       pending    2017-09-22 08:00:05.000
1                    6           17          NULL       NULL       pending    2017-09-22 08:00:06.000
```

Reading your comment, you need this code. It will work well if you do not have different messages to de same JobId

```
 ;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY job_id 
                    ORDER BY id DESC) RowNumber 
                ,* 
         FROM   @table) 
SELECT Max(A.id)        Id 
       ,A.job_id 
       ,Max(IsNull(A.request ,''))  request 
       ,Max(IsNull(A.response,'')) response 
       ,Max(A.status)   status 
       ,Max(A.date_time)date_time 
FROM   @table A 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   cte B 
               WHERE  B.rownumber = 1 
                      AND B.status = 'pending' 
                      AND A.job_id = b.job_id) 
GROUP  BY A.job_id;
```

Result

```
Id          job_id      request    response   status     date_time
----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------
4           16          <message>             pending    2017-09-22 08:00:05.000
6           17          <message>             pending    2017-09-22 08:00:06.000
```

Getting the last status of response and request

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY job_id 
                    ORDER BY id DESC) RowNumber 
                ,* 
         FROM   @table), 
     cte_lstrequest 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY job_id 
                    ORDER BY id DESC) RowNumber 
                ,* 
         FROM   @table 
         WHERE  status = 'pending' 
                AND request IS NOT NULL), 
     cte_lstrespponse 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY job_id 
                    ORDER BY id DESC) RowNumber 
                ,* 
         FROM   @table 
         WHERE  status = 'pending' 
                AND response IS NOT NULL) 
SELECT A.id 
       ,A.job_id 
       ,B.request 
       ,C.response 
       ,A.status 
       ,Isnull(b.date_time, a.date_time) Id 
FROM   cte A 
       LEFT JOIN cte_lstrequest B 
              ON a.job_id = b.job_id 
                 AND a.rownumber = b.rownumber 
       LEFT JOIN cte_lstrespponse C 
              ON a.job_id = c.job_id 
                 AND a.rownumber = c.rownumber 
WHERE  a.rownumber = 1 
       AND a.status = 'pending'
```

Result

```
Id          job_id      request    response   status     Id
----------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------------------
4           16          <message>  NULL       pending    2017-09-22 08:00:05.000
6           17          <message>  NULL       pending    2017-09-22 08:00:06.000
```

Comment: Don't refresh the page, that's why I don't see your A, I was preparing the demo on Rextester. ;) cheers.

Comment: @Sami, Ok no problem.

Comment: Your answer almost got what I want. Since the second row doesn't return the message that was in id 5.

Comment: Reading your comment, you need the code that I added. It will work well if you do not have different messages to de same JobId on the same status

Comment: The message can be different, the only thing that wouldn't change is pending. It needs to get the latest message again too out of the events that are listed.

Comment: Only the last message or all messages? Does it apply to request e response?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(id), job_id FROM testtable 
    WHERE status='pending' GROUP BY job_id DESC;
```

This will select the all jobs that have some row with 'pending' status choosing the latest ID in which the job had 'pending' status.

Comment: _GROUP BY job_id DESC_

Comment: Using the query you specified I get the following error: Column 'testtable.JOB_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: remove MAX(job_id)

Answer (score 0):

Can be easy done with a row_number PARTITION BY JobId ORDER BY date and/or id DESC then take all rows WHERE row_number=1.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql